# TextView. Как сделать анимацию прозрачности только атрибута text, не убирая прозрачность у фона?

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

Имеется TextView со статичным background color и динамичным (приходит с сервера по запросу раз в 10 секунд) text. Как сделать мигающую анимацию текста (мигание в течение n cекунд) при его получении? Стандартная анимация через alpha заставляет мигать весь TextView, включая фон, что не подходит :(

Comment: думаю, проще будет положить TextView в контейнер, и выставить background у контейнера, и анимировать  сам TextView

Comment: Напишите ответ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText );
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(50); 
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myText.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

^ положить TextView в контейнер, и выставить background у контейнера, и анимировать сам TextView
Действительно оказалось проще :)